# Can not hide subview from animation

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create animation with UITableViewCell subviews while Hiding 2 subviews.
In the animation I can still see the subviews.
Any Ideas ?

```
    self.rightCloseButton.hidden = YES;
    self.leftCloseButton.hidden= YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2f animations:^{
        [self changeFramesOfSubviews];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        self.rightCloseButton.hidden = NO;
        self.leftCloseButton.hidden= NO;
    }];
```

Comment: what is the value of self.rightCloseButton and self.leftCloseButton ? Are they definitely pointing at the UIView that you want hidden? or nil?

Comment: Show `[self changeFramesOfSubviews];`.

Answer (score 0):

Well I did not notice  this animation was run inside other animation. removing the first one, solve this.